# Handlebars, how to evaluate the @index

Tags: handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I'm using Ghost as my website base which in turn uses handlebars. I purchased a template to expedite my roll out and am now trying to customize a few items.

So the home page is a masonry style layout of blog entries. The page is built with a `{{#foreach posts}}` loop.

What I want to do is evaluate the `@index` (I assume that it is available in the foreach just like the each loop) so, something like this.

```
{{#foreach posts}}
    if @index = 0
        DO SOMETHING
    elseif @index = 1
        DO SOMETHING
    .
    .
    so on
{{/foreach}}
```

Or better yet a select case would be best. The current lay out is 6 items per page and my goal is to set specific css groups on 0 & 3, 1 & 4, and 2 & 5.

Thank you,
Ty

Comment: http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with the `{{#has}}` helper combined with the data variables accessable within the `{{#foreach}}`-object.

> When inside a {{#foreach}} block, you have access to a set of data variables about the current iteration. These are:
>
> - @index (number) - the 0-based index of the current iteration
> - @number (number) - the 1-based index of the current iteration
> - @key (string) - if iterating over an object, rather than an array, this > contains the object key
> - @first (boolean) - true if this is the first iteration of the collection
> - @last (boolean) - true if this is the last iteration of the collection
> - @odd (boolean) - true if the @index is odd
> - @even (boolean) - true if the @index is even
> - @rowStart (boolean) - true if columns is passed and this iteration signals a row start
> - @rowEnd (boolean) - true if columns is passed and this iteration signals a row end
>
> *Source: http://themes.ghost.org/docs/foreach*

---

> ```
> {{#has number="3"}}{{/has}} // A single number
>
> {{#has number="3, 6, 9"}}{{/has}} // list of numbers
>
> {{#has number="nth:3"}}{{/has}} // special syntax for nth item
>
> {{!-- All of these work exactly the same for index --}}
> ```
>
> *Source: http://themes.ghost.org/docs/has*

So if you want to access 1 & 3 you can do the following:

```
{{#foreach posts}}
    {{#has @index="1, 3"}}
        //DO SOMETHING
    {{/has}}
{{/foreach}}
```

If you're after odd/even then the `@odd` and `@even` data-variables are much simpler to use.

Comment: how do you check if @add or @even?

Comment: @first fixed my issue, nice comment

Answer (score 0):

A better (simpler) solution is just to use CSS ([view on CodePen](http://[enter%20link%20description%20here])):

```
 <head>
    <style>
    .item {
        color: white
    }
    .item:nth-child(6n-2), p:first-child  {
        background: green;
    }
    .item:nth-child(6n-4), p:nth-child(6n-1)  {
        background: red;
    }
    .item:nth-child(6n-3), p:nth-child(6n)  {
        background: blue;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="items">
    <p class="item">Item 0</p>
    <p class="item">Item 1</p>
    <p class="item">Item 2</p>
    <p class="item">Item 3</p>
    <p class="item">Item 4</p>
    <p class="item">Item 5</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You're speaking CSS while he asked about Handlebars.

Answer (score -1):

So, you cannot do comparisons in handlebars. I figured out how to do it through javascript.